# Self contained file tree in C# .net service

Tags: c#, .net, windows, zip

I have a file and directory tree that I would like to include inside a Windows service (.NET 4.0). The service needs to be self-contained. All files should be hidden inside the .exe and no external or imported libraries that you don't find on a standard Windows installation should be used.

So far I have considered:

- Zip file as a resource. Seem to be possible in .NET 4.5 but I am not able to upgrade yet.
- Adding all the files as resource entries in a resource file. This is what I do currently but it become quite cumbersome since I cannot use file extensions and since I need to translate all directory slashes to underscore or something similar.
- Put the whole directory tree as single resources in the project (Build action Resource or Embedded resource?) Unfortunately Folder slashes seem to be renamed to . here and that destroys parts of the path info since I will never know if the dot is a directory break or extension break.
- Make my own file format and store all the files in it with their full path, I hope it will not come to this :)

All suggestions appreciated

Comment: Do all your files have extensions? If so, only the last '.' is an extension break.

Comment: @Michael that is actually a good point! That might actually work! Will do some testing